# is it possible to Override manifest/class ordering from a profile or role?

Tags: puppet

I have a role that calls several profiles in order using contains and chaining like this:

```
class role::buildserver {
  contain ::profile::<all the classes below>
  Class['::profile::chocolatey'] ->
  Class['::profile::jdk'] ->
  Class['::profile::googlechrome'] ->
  Class['::profile::jenkins_install']
}
```

The chain works fine until I include the jenkins_install profile which uses the jenkins module. No matter what I do the jenkins module always gets called first. The module itself contains it's own anchoring order around it's manifests which seems to override my role. Is there a way to override the jenkins module ordering from my role? or tell puppet to ignore it.

This is my jenkins profile

```
class profile::jenkins_install ( 
  $somevariables
)
  class{ '::jenkins':
    configure_firewall => false,
    cli                         => true,  
    plugin_hash           => $plugin_hash,
  } 
contain ::jenkins
}
```

This is the error I get when trying to use the role:

```
(Anchor[jenkins::begin] => Class[Jenkins::Package] => Package[jenkins] => Class[Jenkins::Package] => Class[Jenkins::Config] => Class[Jenkins::Config] => Class[Jenkins::Plugins] => Jenkins::Windows::Plugin[jenkinswalldisplay] => 
Download_file[jenkinswalldisplay.hpi] => Class[Profile::Specflow] => Package[specflow] => Class[Profile::Specflow] => Class[Profile::Tortoisesvn] => Package[tortoisesvn] => Class[Profile::Tortoisesvn] => Class[Profile::Googlechrome] => Package[GoogleChrome] => Class[Profile::Googlechrome] => 
Class[Profile::Jenkins_install] => Class[Jenkins] => Anchor[jenkins::begin])
```

Why does it try to run Jenkins first and last?! I can only think it is the puppet-labs jenkins module using anchor that is causing this. Is there a way to override their ordering?

Comment: Can you check jenkins::windows::plugin and download_file classes? Do they have anything related to the profile or role  class? I presume those are custom classes made by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The module itself contains it's own anchoring order around it's manifests which seems to override my role [...]
>   This is the error I get when trying to use the role [cyclic dependency error]

So in fact the problem is that the class you are including *does not* override any order-of-application constraints declared elsewhere.

> Is there a way to override the jenkins module ordering from my role? or tell puppet to ignore it

No, and it does not make sense to do so.  If the order-of-application constraints you have expressed are genuine and appropriate, then having other resources under management as well cannot invalidate them.

The true problem seems to be that you are expressing unneeded constraints, and some of those conflict with constraints expressed elsewhere.  Note in particular that needing to have one physical resource in place in order for another to be *useful* does not necessarily mean that one needs to be *managed* before the other.  In particular, it is not obvious to me why class `role::buildserver` needs to express *any* of the order constraints it does.

> Why does it try to run Jenkins first and last?

It doesn't.  The message excerpt depicts how the order-of-application requirements you have placed form a cycle.  It could express that cycle equivalently with any resource in it as start and end points.  Puppet doesn't apply any of the resources participating in the cycle, because it cannot simultaneously satisfy all the order-of-application constraints.

Some of the order constraints that contribute to the cycle appear to come from class `::jenkins` and from the profile classes you have named, none of which you have presented, so I cannot confidently offer a specific solution, but you should look for how to break the cycle by removing unneeded constraints.  It may be that you need to do this with several constraints, in several places.

Comment: In my role example above I tried to keep it short and have actually omitted the resources that actually needed to be managed in order which I realise now was a mistake. There are a couple that do need to come before Jenkins (jdk and one that manages chocolatey). However I take your point that unnecessary contraints on my part could be the problem. I will spend some time fixing that and will update after

Comment: Removing/simplifying constraints solved my problems. Your most helpful comment was that puppet expresses the cycle "equivalently with any resource in it as start and end points". This helped me look elsewhere for my problems instead of focusing so much on jenkins module. Thanks